# Can this clause be used with both present and future reference?

Tags: tense

> I don’t mind **what you do**.  (1)
>  Let me know **who wins**.   (2)
>
> -- [*Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/)

CGEL says the two examples’ subordinate clauses are written as ‘deictic futures’. There would be no ambiguity in (2), but there seems to be one between present and future time in (1). Can (1)’s subordinate clause be used only as a deictic future, or can it be used as a deictic present in some contexts?

Comment: Can you provide a reference supporting *"In CGEL, the two examples’ subordinate clauses are written as **deictic future**"*? I don't understand the terminology in this context - in fact, I don't see how [deixis](http://deictic.askdefine.com/) relates to these two sentences any more than it does to *any* utterances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Tense is regarded as a deictic category because it involves 'pointing' in a specific temporal 'direction' from the moment of utterance, just as *this* and *that* or *I* and *you* point in specific spatial directions. *Deictic* tense is apparently current jargon for the *simple* (or *direct* or *absolute*) tenses which locate the event at the time at which you're pointing, as opposed to *relative* tenses like perfects which locate the event before the time at which you're pointing.

Comment: @StoneyB: Not your fault, I'm sure, but that's about as clear as mud to me. Is it just a roundabout way of OP asking whether his examples can be semantically identical to *what you are doing* and *who is winning* in certain contexts? I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You got it. Can "what you do" point to the immediate present? My answer (below) says "No, but it can refer to the *generic*, indefinite present we use in "FumbleFingers does this sort of thing very well".

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, we seem to have exposed a "deictic" dimension to the imperative *Let me know [something]*. On your part, at least, since you say it always means *tell me **in the future*** in your dialect (never *tell me **now***). I don't really see that anyway, but I find it hard to believe such an obscure and sporadically-observed nuance could be the focus of OP's enquiry here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No, that's **our** problem :) ... OP is concerned with "I don't mind": whether it has to mean "I don't mind what you do in the future" or if it can also mean "I don't mind what you are doing now".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think characterizing (1) as a deictic future is dubious. It *may* be deictic future in the right context:

> I know you haven’t decided yet, but I wanted to tell that I don’t mind what you do.

But in another context it may be a ‘generic’ present, signifying the addressee's habitual practice:

> Usually I don’t mind what you do, but in this case I think you’re behaving badly.

For a deictic present, however (if I’m understanding the CGEL use of this term—I take it to mean a construction which indicates specifically present action), I think you have to use the progressive construction:

> Go right ahead. I don’t mind what you’re doing at all.

Context is everything. (2), for instance, is unambiguous only because the imperative *let me know* necessarily points to a future action. In another context, *who wins* may have generic force. For instance, Grantland Rice's famous verse “For when the One Great Scorer comes/ To mark against your name,/ He writes - not that you won or lost -/ But how you played the Game” may be paraphrased

> What matters in any contest is not who wins but how the game is played.

Comment: Actually, #2 is unambiguous only because of the *verb form* "wins". If I said *"Let me know who **won**"*, that would imply a reference a past winner. But if I said *"Let me know **the winner**"*, I could be referring to a past, present *or* future winner.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmmm ... All imperatives are inherently futurive; and in US usage, "let me know" implies futurity even more strongly - "let me know when you find out". But in that respect it accommodates both 'wins' and 'won' in a futurive sense, because *WIN* is an achievement verb which can only be known and communicated after the fact. Cisatlantically, at least, I can say while the game's in progress "I'm going to bed now. Let me know who won."

Comment: I can't really argue with that final example, but it does rely on interpreting "let me know" as a request to be informed *at some future time*. I was thinking in terms of it being an "immediate" instruction - *Tell me **right now** who won* (I'm asking about a past event, and I want an answer *within the present conversational context*, not sometime in the future).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That appears to be a difference between your dialect and mine. "Let me know" would not be used as an immediate demand over here; it's used when "tell me now" is precluded.

Comment: Weird. It's certainly not a US/UK split though - I can find plenty of examples in Google Books like [“I can't get into details right now. Just let me know what you discovered.”](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22now+just+let+me+know+what+you+discovered%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) which are obviously American, and obviously expect an *immediate* answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the example you give the speaker asks for an analysis the next day: ***Take your time with it**, Stan. … Just put it in my desk under lock and key **after you’re done with it during the day***. … *Just let me know what you discovered*.”

Comment: Ah well, I guess I should have checked the context of that one more thoroughly. All I know is ***I*** don't have a problem with saying *"Just let me know where you are and I'll come and pick you up"* in contexts where I expect the other person to reply *right now* telling me where they are.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And in the same context I'd say "Tell me where you are and I'll..." or (more gently)  "If you can tell me where you are ..."

Comment: I don't deny that I would *tend* to phrase it like that too. I just don't see anything *wrong* with, for example, ["Look, this is likely to be a long call. Let me know your number and I'll call you back."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22call+Let+me+know+your+number%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm definitely with Stoney on this one; I've never heard an American speak like that. We would definitely use "tell me". "Let me know" is pretty much always used to refer to the future (pretty much = I can't think of an example where it *isn't*, but that doesn't mean an exception doesn't exist!) One of my favorite things about ELL is learning about differences between UK and US English that you'd never have thought of before. :)

Comment: @WendiKidd: It may be that I'm just more "linguistically tolerant" than the average (or, God forbid, that I'm *ignorant/undiscriminating*). Apart from ELU/ELL, I've had very little to do with "formal, academic grammar" over the last 40 years, and my own "inner grammarian" is mainly self-taught on the basis of what I read and hear other people say. But I must stress that I'm only saying my last link above, for example, doesn't strike me as ***wrong*** - I'm not saying it's particularly common, even in my experience.